# Падает Mongo при $lookup c pipeline

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

При попытке сделать присоединение коллекции orders к items:

```
db.items.aggregate(
[{
  $lookup:
         {
           from: "orders",
           let: {id: "$_id"},
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    {$and:
                       [
                         {$eq: [ "$item_id",  "$$id" ]},
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }
           ],
           as: "orders"
         }
}] , {"allowDiskUse": true}
)
```

Происходит падение базы, в логах вот это

```
[conn4] Invariant failure Hit a MONGO_UNREACHABLE! src/mongo/db/query/collation/collation_spec.cpp 90
2019-09-16T13:31:12.093+0000 F  -        [conn4] 

***aborting after invariant() failure


2019-09-16T13:31:12.198+0000 F  -        [conn4] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
 0x56443e4c0741 0x56443e4bff3e 0x56443e4bffd6 0x7f2f78491890 0x7f2f780cce97 0x7f2f780ce801 0x56443c944a52 0x56443e3bfa74 0x56443d3cce9d 0x56443d3cdb35 0x56443d3ced38 0x56443d3d0fea 0x56443d3d1538 0x56443cbbb37f 0x56443cbb9684 0x56443cbba1fb 0x56443ddc058e 0x56443ddc0fb7 0x56443de0848d 0x56443d3a1065 0x56443d3a0ed6 0x56443d3a1618 0x56443d3e9180 0x56443d3e990d 0x56443d0f178d 0x56443d0f608f 0x56443d0e97a5 0x56443ce13859 0x56443ce14f13 0x56443ce15dce 0x56443ce166a0 0x56443ce046cc 0x56443ce1028c 0x56443ce0bc0f 0x56443ce0ee8c 0x56443dbefd52 0x56443ce0962d 0x56443ce0c8c3 0x56443ce0acf7 0x56443ce0bb6b 0x56443ce0ee8c 0x56443dbf01bb 0x56443e252874 0x7f2f784866db 0x7f2f781af88f
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"555B94758000","o":"287C741","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"287BF3E"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"287BFD6"},{"b":"7F84F5092000","o":"12890"},{"b":"7F84F4CA1000","o":"3EE97","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7F84F4CA1000","o":"40801","s":"abort"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"D00A52","s":"_ZN5mongo22invariantFailedWithMsgEPKcRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES1_j"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"277BA74","s":"_ZNK5mongo13CollationSpec6toBSONEv"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"1788E9D"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"1789B35","s":"_ZN5mongo9PipelineD15prepareExecutorEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_10CollectionERKNS_15NamespaceStringEPNS_8PipelineERKN5boost13intrusive_ptrINS_17ExpressionContextEEEbRKNSB_INS_18DocumentSourceSortEEESt10unique_ptrINS_36GroupFromFirstDocumentTransformationESt14default_deleteISL_EERKNS_11DepsTrackerERKNS_7BSONObjEPKNS_18AggregationRequestERKyPSS_S10_"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"178AD38","s":"_ZN5mongo9PipelineD30buildInnerQueryExecutorGenericEPNS_10CollectionERKNS_15NamespaceStringEPKNS_18AggregationRequestEPNS_8PipelineE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"178CFEA","s":"_ZN5mongo9PipelineD23buildInnerQueryExecutorEPNS_10CollectionERKNS_15NamespaceStringEPKNS_18AggregationRequestEPNS_8PipelineE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"178D538","s":"_ZN5mongo9PipelineD42buildAndAttachInnerQueryExecutorToPipelineEPNS_10CollectionERKNS_15NamespaceStringEPKNS_18AggregationRequestEPNS_8PipelineE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"F7737F","s":"_ZN5mongo24MongoInterfaceStandalone40attachCursorSourceToPipelineForLocalReadERKN5boost13intrusive_ptrINS_17ExpressionContextEEEPNS_8PipelineE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"F75684","s":"_ZN5mongo24MongoInterfaceStandalone28attachCursorSourceToPipelineERKN5boost13intrusive_ptrINS_17ExpressionContextEEEPNS_8PipelineE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"F761FB","s":"_ZN5mongo24MongoInterfaceStandalone12makePipelineERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EERKN5boost13intrusive_ptrINS_17ExpressionContextEEENS_21MongoProcessInterface19MakePipelineOptionsE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"217C58E","s":"_ZN5mongo20DocumentSourceLookUp13buildPipelineERKNS_8DocumentE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"217CFB7","s":"_ZN5mongo20DocumentSourceLookUp7getNextEv"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"21C448D","s":"_ZN5mongo8Pipeline7getNextEv"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"175D065","s":"_ZN5mongo18PipelineProxyStage11getNextBsonEv"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"175CED6","s":"_ZN5mongo18PipelineProxyStage6doWorkEPm"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"175D618","s":"_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"17A5180","s":"_ZN5mongo16PlanExecutorImpl12_getNextImplEPNS_11SnapshottedINS_7BSONObjEEEPNS_8RecordIdE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"17A590D","s":"_ZN5mongo16PlanExecutorImpl7getNextEPNS_7BSONObjEPNS_8RecordIdE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"14AD78D"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"14B208F","s":"_ZN5mongo12runAggregateEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_15NamespaceStringERKNS_18AggregationRequestERKNS_7BSONObjERKSt6vectorINS_9PrivilegeESaISC_EEPNS_3rpc21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"14A57A5"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11CF859"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11D0F13"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11D1DCE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11D26A0","s":"_ZN5mongo23ServiceEntryPointCommon13handleRequestEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7MessageERKNS0_5HooksE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11C06CC","s":"_ZN5mongo23ServiceEntryPointMongod13handleRequestEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7MessageE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11CC28C","s":"_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_processMessageENS0_11ThreadGuardE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11C7C0F","s":"_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_runNextInGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11CAE8C"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"1FABD52","s":"_ZN5mongo9transport26ServiceExecutorSynchronous8scheduleESt8functionIFvvEENS0_15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS0_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11C562D","s":"_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine22_scheduleNextWithGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardENS_9transport15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS2_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameENS0_9OwnershipE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11C88C3","s":"_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_sourceCallbackENS_6StatusE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11C6CF7","s":"_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine14_sourceMessageENS0_11ThreadGuardE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11C7B6B","s":"_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_runNextInGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardE"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"11CAE8C"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"1FAC1BB"},{"b":"555B94758000","o":"260E874"},{"b":"7F84F5092000","o":"76DB"},{"b":"7F84F4CA1000","o":"12188F","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "4.2.0", "gitVersion" : "a4b751dcf51dd249c5865812b390cfd1c0129c30", "compiledModules" : [ "enterprise" ], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.15.0-62-generic", "version" : "#69-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 4 20:55:53 UTC 2019", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "555B94758000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4EE35FDC2FB7C1DC9AE0FA065B98E2666BC5E79C" }, { "b" : "7FFFBC3FD000", "path" : "linux-vdso.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "17ABBA294C8661C069F5408AC1D74F121AD71734" }, { "b" : "7F84F7C96000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpmibs.so.30", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "0B3EDB4E9A96E0B0AB1E2301298314F0509D6E69" }, { "b" : "7F84F7A87000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsensors.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B21B5590FA3766E5B4D33C6619E7FC3C6EFB343B" }, { "b" : "7F84F787A000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpci.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2E20D61921C8C482DDCC973352AA823D54A6C75E" }, { "b" : "7F84F7676000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "25AD56E902E23B490A9CCDB08A9744D89CB95BCC" }, { "b" : "7F84F740D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpagent.so.30", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "496196D52AF5622F412B8B4A38075E7509426548" }, { "b" : "7F84F7203000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "93E8EE4A51AEB0FCCDE2C0CEF42F3F43637482E7" }, { "b" : "7F84F6F27000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmp.so.30", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "11C46888E6D931CC8C4733FA2E9DDF66AA685C33" }, { "b" : "7F84F6A5C000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CB6876717C83B0CC01C3C919B9B6E86D8554F546" }, { "b" : "7F84F680A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "70EEF126558D1559A0A4E334FB68E4E9AABE90CB" }, { "b" : "7F84F65FC000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C14042EC7BD22B9A07D2C16563FE3C2606F52AB7" }, { "b" : "7F84F63E1000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "ABB7E3F40302E6509DAD1F91DFB1F04B6A5FD072" }, { "b" : "7F84F6196000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "00F419F64B0E70D8C5EEF7050369AA40B2A6E090" }, { "b" : "7F84F5F17000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1C6BC2C0699CE0F7E848CA0B267E0CF07553F6AB" }, { "b" : "7F84F5B79000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A33761AB8FB485311B3C85BF4253099D7CABE653" }, { "b" : "7F84F595E000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "390E9CC4C215314B6D8ADE6D6E28F8518418039C" }, { "b" : "7F84F56D1000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "439A262CC0127BA401707DEC7A28884D617550E0" }, { "b" : "7F84F54C9000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9826FBDF57ED7D6965131074CB3C08B1009C1CD8" }, { "b" : "7F84F52B1000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "41BDC55C07D5E5B1D8AB38E2C19B1F535855E084" }, { "b" : "7F84F5092000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "28C6AADE70B2D40D1F0F3D0A1A0CAD1AB816448F" }, { "b" : "7F84F4CA1000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B417C0BA7CC5CF06D1D1BED6652CEDB9253C60D0" }, { "b" : "7F84F8111000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "64DF1B961228382FE18684249ED800AB1DCEAAD4" }, { "b" : "7F84F4A84000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "EF3E006DFE3132A41D4D4DC0E407D6EA658E11C4" }, { "b" : "7F84F4866000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "81D246A5D1C93AD88B13BB890B6A4D784FF9C421" }, { "b" : "7F84F4469000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.26", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CA3489D4F5936D6DD4FA45CC902CBDE6E90C4557" }, { "b" : "7F84F424F000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B7FE43B6E487E0DD408E0F98008AAEA12EECC66C" }, { "b" : "7F84F400E000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A1A98DB481968073636BBAECB561A3EA8ED198AE" }, { "b" : "7F84F3CA9000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E5AE5C31F804BE96532D0DB2091F19E472F2D4A0" }, { "b" : "7F84F39D3000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "69FBCF425EE6DF03DE93B82FBC2FC33790E68A96" }, { "b" : "7F84F37A1000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F400D5D643A7F9696DF0E6148FA99BEE6C1BDDF7" }, { "b" : "7F84F359D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C0CB7E35A4566A443F99DFBC1A54D3A0677C8A10" }, { "b" : "7F84F3392000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D78D71E8E016A534281B25B97CD7E5E9DB5FE00A" }, { "b" : "7F84F316D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4F00E5207693FDC249DA42EC6472ACA6A7B929AE" }, { "b" : "7F84F2F50000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BA5BF9A5C44F48C647E9D8270A5421AE81CCAD61" }, { "b" : "7F84F2D34000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "69465D8AA6B19086ABF2455A703F9168BF82A69F" }, { "b" : "7F84F2B26000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CDAF1F1946846941F9D06414EC8C812D131A168E" }, { "b" : "7F84F28EE000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "810686AF0D5FD350A4FB1CC4B5AFF44A05C102CB" }, { "b" : "7F84F26E5000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C2376C5B831991591F1A67B976758185F86896D8" }, { "b" : "7F84F2458000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "69BDEE5FA0FEEDF317308BE850F78761861D520A" }, { "b" : "7F84F21B6000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "315D74995AAA32DE4D15BA25F335066988B1B230" }, { "b" : "7F84F1F80000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6673972A1C24A89EBAFBAE696188A4CB26C6DDEB" }, { "b" : "7F84F1D6A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "430827C33259C12248CF44B91A9A9821114376F5" }, { "b" : "7F84F1A3B000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8DBD451EA5651283905E16FA7DFA9908688893A3" }, { "b" : "7F84F16BD000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "0E2784298E7D3F4D894FE130ACEFA77C3E624F72" }, { "b" : "7F84F14AA000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6036B89A3BB671B32E01464C0C82BFA016186352" }, { "b" : "7F84F1274000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C20D4B3BA13FCDCC3BF6857689BA9FC70BE3F6A5" }, { "b" : "7F84F1040000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "842BDF0B0EAAB82E19F1EABFC38769F4040FBE31" }, { "b" : "7F84F0DBF000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D40EA9B5EC5BC46799E4A412319617BD38BE9341" }, { "b" : "7F84F0BBB000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F463E107B099910463BC32E837C73D341A52C27B" }, { "b" : "7F84F0992000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "93A0931B1C2818F0EA224CE6FE5E31E84A9B55BB" }, { "b" : "7F84F0783000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "669D4CCE42FA4382796EFFCF0C16F459F4382C4C" }, { "b" : "7F84F0539000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4B80C543356EE0AF9039EFE7C9EA1CC1F74C426A" }, { "b" : "7F84F0230000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BCE351987CF42B3D258B09F0CAC867758D935086" }, { "b" : "7F84F0028000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3555B5F599C9787DFDDBF9E8DF6F706B9044D985" }, { "b" : "7F84EFE23000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sasl2/liblogin.so", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F74A279C265B0FEC0186260FC84749911A909A59" }, { "b" : "7F84EFC1C000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sasl2/libsasldb.so", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9CEB11BBC12C2D2DAF0BA8BA0648105B2D66E4B6" }, { "b" : "7F84EF873000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-5.3.so", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2B17894B4DF79DA6735BD54381B75402BD654796" }, { "b" : "7F84EF66D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sasl2/libcrammd5.so", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F956F817302B843D1FA74AF8577DDCF3CC4855B7" }, { "b" : "7F84EF468000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sasl2/libplain.so", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AAA34050DD1BAF7809DF19549571A2F082276782" }, { "b" : "7F84EF25F000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sasl2/libntlm.so", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "11357A5DA0B160164C8DF2F4DB2B9E00B0540245" }, { "b" : "7F84EF05A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sasl2/libanonymous.so", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "EAC878F70ADD404EF9E0EE9705ED015732F3F8F0" }, { "b" : "7F84EEE4C000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sasl2/libdigestmd5.so", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F64BDE43D36E8005E4AB971AF5C9DC3BA56417AE" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x555b96fd4741]
 mongod(+0x287BF3E) [0x555b96fd3f3e]
 mongod(+0x287BFD6) [0x555b96fd3fd6]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f84f50a4890]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0xC7) [0x7f84f4cdfe97]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7f84f4ce1801]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo22invariantFailedWithMsgEPKcRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES1_j+0x0) [0x555b95458a52]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo13CollationSpec6toBSONEv+0x1D54) [0x555b96ed3a74]
 mongod(+0x1788E9D) [0x555b95ee0e9d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9PipelineD15prepareExecutorEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_10CollectionERKNS_15NamespaceStringEPNS_8PipelineERKN5boost13intrusive_ptrINS_17ExpressionContextEEEbRKNSB_INS_18DocumentSourceSortEEESt10unique_ptrINS_36GroupFromFirstDocumentTransformationESt14default_deleteISL_EERKNS_11DepsTrackerERKNS_7BSONObjEPKNS_18AggregationRequestERKyPSS_S10_+0x805) [0x555b95ee1b35]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9PipelineD30buildInnerQueryExecutorGenericEPNS_10CollectionERKNS_15NamespaceStringEPKNS_18AggregationRequestEPNS_8PipelineE+0x348) [0x555b95ee2d38]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9PipelineD23buildInnerQueryExecutorEPNS_10CollectionERKNS_15NamespaceStringEPKNS_18AggregationRequestEPNS_8PipelineE+0x56A) [0x555b95ee4fea]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9PipelineD42buildAndAttachInnerQueryExecutorToPipelineEPNS_10CollectionERKNS_15NamespaceStringEPKNS_18AggregationRequestEPNS_8PipelineE+0x48) [0x555b95ee5538]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo24MongoInterfaceStandalone40attachCursorSourceToPipelineForLocalReadERKN5boost13intrusive_ptrINS_17ExpressionContextEEEPNS_8PipelineE+0x18F) [0x555b956cf37f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo24MongoInterfaceStandalone28attachCursorSourceToPipelineERKN5boost13intrusive_ptrINS_17ExpressionContextEEEPNS_8PipelineE+0x24) [0x555b956cd684]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo24MongoInterfaceStandalone12makePipelineERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EERKN5boost13intrusive_ptrINS_17ExpressionContextEEENS_21MongoProcessInterface19MakePipelineOptionsE+0x8B) [0x555b956ce1fb]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo20DocumentSourceLookUp13buildPipelineERKNS_8DocumentE+0x1BE) [0x555b968d458e]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo20DocumentSourceLookUp7getNextEv+0xF7) [0x555b968d4fb7]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8Pipeline7getNextEv+0x3D) [0x555b9691c48d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18PipelineProxyStage11getNextBsonEv+0x35) [0x555b95eb5065]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18PipelineProxyStage6doWorkEPm+0x46) [0x555b95eb4ed6]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm+0x68) [0x555b95eb5618]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16PlanExecutorImpl12_getNextImplEPNS_11SnapshottedINS_7BSONObjEEEPNS_8RecordIdE+0x230) [0x555b95efd180]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16PlanExecutorImpl7getNextEPNS_7BSONObjEPNS_8RecordIdE+0x4D) [0x555b95efd90d]
 mongod(+0x14AD78D) [0x555b95c0578d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12runAggregateEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_15NamespaceStringERKNS_18AggregationRequestERKNS_7BSONObjERKSt6vectorINS_9PrivilegeESaISC_EEPNS_3rpc21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE+0x277F) [0x555b95c0a08f]
 mongod(+0x14A57A5) [0x555b95bfd7a5]
 mongod(+0x11CF859) [0x555b95927859]
 mongod(+0x11D0F13) [0x555b95928f13]
 mongod(+0x11D1DCE) [0x555b95929dce]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo23ServiceEntryPointCommon13handleRequestEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7MessageERKNS0_5HooksE+0x540) [0x555b9592a6a0]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo23ServiceEntryPointMongod13handleRequestEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7MessageE+0x3C) [0x555b959186cc]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_processMessageENS0_11ThreadGuardE+0xEC) [0x555b9592428c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_runNextInGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardE+0x17F) [0x555b9591fc0f]
 mongod(+0x11CAE8C) [0x555b95922e8c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9transport26ServiceExecutorSynchronous8scheduleESt8functionIFvvEENS0_15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS0_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameE+0x182) [0x555b96703d52]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine22_scheduleNextWithGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardENS_9transport15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS2_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameENS0_9OwnershipE+0x10D) [0x555b9591d62d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_sourceCallbackENS_6StatusE+0x843) [0x555b959208c3]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine14_sourceMessageENS0_11ThreadGuardE+0x2E7) [0x555b9591ecf7]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_runNextInGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardE+0xDB) [0x555b9591fb6b]
 mongod(+0x11CAE8C) [0x555b95922e8c]
 mongod(+0x1FAC1BB) [0x555b967041bb]
 mongod(+0x260E874) [0x555b96d66874]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x76DB) [0x7f84f50996db]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x3F) [0x7f84f4dc288f]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

Также один раз появилась такая ошибка:

Command failed with error 13548: 'BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 240394258 bytes, past the 64MB limit.' on server

Comment: Это Вам скорее на монговский [багтрекер](https://jira.mongodb.org) надо, чем сюда. Падение сервера - это явный баг, и кроме разработчиков никто его Вам не исправит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После обращения на багтрекер mongodb выяснилось, что это связано с присутствием в одной объединяемой коллекции объекта "сollation" и отсутствие его в другой.

Результат команды db.getCollectionInfos();

```
{
                "name" : "orders",
                "type" : "collection",
                "options" : {
                        "collation" : {
                                "locale" : "ru",
                                "caseLevel" : false,
                                "caseFirst" : "off",
                                "strength" : 3,
                                "numericOrdering" : false,
                                "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
                                "maxVariable" : "punct",
                                "normalization" : false,
                                "backwards" : false,
                                "version" : "57.1"
                        }
                },
                "info" : {
                        "readOnly" : false,
                        "uuid" : UUID("269bd5be-6e3a-49f6-af14-0ce3f1a31212")
                },
                "idIndex" : {
                        "v" : 2,
                        "key" : {
                                "_id" : 1
                        },
                        "name" : "_id_",
                        "ns" : "fdatabase.orders",
                        "collation" : {
                                "locale" : "ru",
                                "caseLevel" : false,
                                "caseFirst" : "off",
                                "strength" : 3,
                                "numericOrdering" : false,
                                "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
                                "maxVariable" : "punct",
                                "normalization" : false,
                                "backwards" : false,
                                "version" : "57.1"
                        }
                }
        },
 {
                "name" : "items",
                "type" : "collection",
                "options" : {

                },
                "info" : {
                        "readOnly" : false,
                        "uuid" : UUID("808700ba-bca9-4ae4-88b9-6a42e32deff7")
                },
                "idIndex" : {
                        "v" : 2,
                        "key" : {
                                "_id" : 1
                        },
                        "name" : "_id_",
                        "ns" : "fdatabase._items"
                }
        }
```

Это было принято как баг и передано команде разработки на рассмотрение.
После создания новой коллекции orders без сollation и переноса туда данных со старой коллекции, падения прекратились.

Comment: а можете разместить ссылку на обращение?

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-43350